# PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync generates every time a new channel URI

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

Is it correct that everytime i call `PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()` to get my push channel a **new** `Uri` for my App is generated? I'mean the expiration time of the channel is about 1 month, but why is there generated a new one if it is not expired? I'need to send the URI everytime to my push server who needs to update the database. For 100 Users this might be okay, but we got > 2mio users.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't change that often but may change before the expiry time if requested again. How are you making multiple calls?
If I put this in an app I get the same thing both times.

```
var uri = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri.Uri);

var uri2 = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri2.Uri);
```

If you're testing this by making the call after restarting the app, during development, and you're rebuilding between launches that may be the cause, as rebuilding can change the app's identity and so be seen as a different client to the notification system.

Comment: Hi Matt, indeed i'm launching the App multiple times without rebuilding it, but with debugger attached. However, could it be possible that system changes can cause the app to get a new identity? For instance i've taken ownership of %PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps

Comment: Hello, Matt. Maybe you know how avoid duplicates when calling CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync when new version of app is released?